# using combobox selectedItem on a function

Tags: java, swing

i have an function connexion to a database
and i have a code that i have a select and display elements in a combobox
so i want pass on class connexion.java the combobox selectedItem becaue it contains the all of databases that i have
so i want tha classe connexion be dynamic so pass the element selected on this class
i don"t know how can i do that please help me

```
public class Connexion {
  private static Connection conn;

    {       
           try { 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}

           try { 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mohammedia", "root", "123456"); 
} catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }          
              }
public static Connection getconx()
{ 
    return conn; 
}  
}
```

Comment: I read the question three times and still I do not know what you are asking. I would suggest you start by adding some points and capital letters to make it more readable. You also mention a combobox but that does not show in the code you posted. In short, make it more clear what you are actually asking

Comment: In addition to Robin's advice, consider posting a well-formatted and properly indented code. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Okey sorry because i don"t speak very well english

Comment: Okey so this is the code for combobox
it's for diplay all of databases that i have 
so in class Connexion.java i want call a selectedItem in function connexion
means in place that i do every moment the name of database i want that be related of what combobox select

Comment: jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
        try{
            Connection conn = Connexion.getconx();
               String sql = "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;";         
                PreparedStatement prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet res=prest.executeQuery();
        while(res.next()){
               jComboBox2.addItem(res.getString("schema_name")) ;
                    }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }

Answer (score 0):

A `JComboBox` accepts any kind of object, so you can simply do something like this.

```
Connection con = new Connection();
JComboBox box = getBox();
box.addItem(con);
```

And to retreive the value:

```
JComboBox box = getBox();
Connection con = (Connection)box.getSelectedItem();
```

However in your Connection class you must override the `toString()` function, because this is used to display the box.

```
class Connection
{
     public String toString()
     {
         return "BoxItemDisplayvalue";    <--- here you must put something meaningfull which is displayed in the box.
     }
 }
```

So you can instantiate a connection representing the connection that you want, and when the user selects an item from the combobox, you will have the connection it represents.

Comment: i want add the variable of selectedItem here                                      public static Connection getconx(    String dbase)
{ 
    return conn; 
}

Comment: Connection conn = Connexion.getconx();
 String box= jComboBox1.getActionCommand();

Comment: But i don't think that is true because my Class Connection in URL it contains a name of an database and me i want this name will change in function of the item selected in Combobox

Answer (score 0):

Use this class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

import sun.jdbc.rowset.CachedRowSet;

public class SQLConnection {

    private static Connection con = null;

    private static BasicDataSource dataSource;


    //we can enable and disable connection pool here
   //true means connection pool enabled,false means disabled
    private static boolean useConnectionPool = true;

    private static int count=0;

    private SQLConnection() {

        /*
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(""));
        maxActive = properties.get("maxActive");
         */
    }

    public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaname";
    public static String password = "moibesoft";
    public static String userName = "root";
    public static String driverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static int maxActive = 20;
    public static int maxIdle = 10;

    private static final String DB_URL = "driver.classs.name";
    private static final String DB_USERNAME = "database.username";
    static {
    /*Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\CollegeBell\\properties\\DatabaseConnection.properties"));
            //properties.load(new FileInputStream("E:\\vali\\CollegeBell\\WebContent\\WEB-INF"));
            //properties.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\DatabaseConnection.properties"));
            url = properties.getProperty(DB_URL);
            System.out.println(url);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(maxActive);
        dataSource.setMinIdle(maxIdle);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);

    }

    //public static Connection getConnection(String opendFrom) throws SQLException,
    public static Connection getConnection(String openedFrom) {
        count++;
           System.out.println("nos of connection opened till now="+count);
        System.out.println("Connection opended from "+openedFrom);
    //  System.out.println("Connection Opended ");
        try {

            if (useConnectionPool) {
                con = dataSource.getConnection();
                System.out.println(dataSource.getMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis());
                //dataSource.setMaxWait(15000);
                System.out.println(dataSource.getMaxWait());
                System.out.println(count );
            } else {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            }
        }

            //System.out.println("Connection : " + con.toString());
            catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, String closedFrom)
            {

        //System.out.println("Connection closed from: " + con.toString());
    //  System.out.println("Connection closed from: " + closedFrom);
        //log.info("Connection closed from: " + closedFrom);
        if(con != null){
             count--;
             System.out.println("Connection count value after closing="+count);
        System.out.println("Connection closed from: " + closedFrom);
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    //added by nehal
    public static void closeStatement(Statement ps, String closedFrom)
    {
if(ps != null){
System.out.println("Statement closed from: " + closedFrom);
try {
    ps.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}


    public static void closePreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps, String closedFrom)
    {
if(ps != null){
System.out.println("Statement closed from: " + closedFrom);
try {
    ps.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

    public static void closeResultSet(ResultSet rs, String closedFrom)
     {
if(rs != null){
System.out.println("ResultSet closed from: " + closedFrom);
try {
    rs.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
    //added by nehal

    /*public static ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws Exception {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        CachedRowSet crset = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            crset = new CachedRowSet();
            crset.populate(rs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
        return crset;
    }

    public static int executeUpdate(String query) throws Exception {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int rows = -1;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rows = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }

    public static boolean execute(String query) throws Exception {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean rowsreturned = false;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rowsreturned = stmt.execute(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
        return rowsreturned;
    }*/

    /*
     * public static void closeConnection(Connection con) { try { con.close();
     * con=null; } catch (SQLException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     * e.printStackTrace(); } }
     */

}
```

Comment: But where is the relation with the elements of ComboBox

Comment: use this connection obj, get all the values from db and display in the combo box.

Comment: JComboBox box = getBox(); where is the method getBox()

Comment: refer once, it might help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: you mean like this: JComboBox box=JComboBox.getActionCommand();

Comment: MySqlConnection connection = null;            
            string hostname = "localhost";
            string database = "aparece_hoteldb";
            string username = "root";
            string password = "";
            connection = new MySqlConnection("host=" + hostname + 
                                            ";database=" + database + 
                                            ";username=" + username + 
                                            ";password=" + password + ";"); so here in place that i write  string database = "aparece_hoteldb";

Comment: string database = "aparece_hoteldb"; so string database='the string that selectedItem from combobox)

Answer (score 0):

For what i understand, you have 2 classes..
One the gui where you have a comboBox with the schema name where u want to get connected.
So you have to have a `EventListener` to "listen" when the submit button is pressed.

For example:

```
Connection con = null;
JButton submitButton = new JButton("Confirm db");
submitButton.addActionListener(new MyConnectionListener());

..
//Could be inner class
class MyConnectionListener implements ActionListener {

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
         if(cmb.getSelectedItem() != null){
           con = Connection.getConx(cmb.getSelectedItem().toString());
         }

 }

}
```

And in your Connexion class

```
public class Connexion {

public static Connection getconx(String schema)
{ 
 Connection conn = null;
          try { 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}

           try { 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+schema, "root", "123456"); 
} catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }          
              } 


   return conn; 
}  
}
```

Comment: Yes thank's even if i do it with another way but this code it seems better than my mine

Comment: @cisco.nat consider accepting any answer and upvoting them who help you